# Average of 10 numbers in Assembly langauge

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I am trying to find the average of 10 numbers in Assembly, but am not getting the right answer. What could be the error?

I have just started using Assembly language, so please don't suggest more intermediate levels of code. Any change to make for the mentioned code would be appreciated.

```
org 100h

mov bx, 5000h 


mov [bx], 10h

inc bx 

mov [bx], 20h

inc bx

mov [bx], 30h 

inc bx

mov [bx], 40h

inc bx 

mov [bx], 50h

inc bx

mov [bx], 60h 

inc bx

mov [bx], 70h

inc bx 

mov [bx], 80h

inc bx

mov [bx], 90h 

inc bx

mov [bx], 100h



mov al, 0h

mov cx, 10h


lab: add al, [bx]

dec bx

loop lab



mov bl, 10h

div bl
```

Answer (score 3):

`10h` is a heaxecimal constant with the value of 16.

```
mov cx, 10h
```

Loads 16 to `CX`, so the loop loads 16 numbers, 6 (or 5, see below) past the end of your array.

```
mov bl, 10h
```

Loads 16 to `BL`, so you divide by 16.

Similarly, those constants that you load aren't 10, 20, ... 100, they're 16, 32, ... 256.

Note that 256 does not fit in a single byte, so this doesn't store the value 256 in a single byte at the address `BX`, as that isn't possible.

You take the average of 16 numbers. The first 9 of those are ones you want, the next two are the two bytes 0x00 and 0x01 (0x100 stored as two bytes), and the next 5 are whatever happens to be in memory.

Hexadecimal constants are denoted by the suffix `h`.

Another problem is that the sum of the numbers you add doesn't fit in a single byte, so accumulating them in AL won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Holy crap, does emu8086 really assemble `mov [bx], 90h` to `mov byte ptr [bx], imm8`, but `mov [bx], 100h` to word ptr, imm16?  That's totally insane.  A good assembler should error on an ambiguous instruction like either of those.  (Unfortunately emu8086 isn't the only bad assembler; GAS assembles `add $1, (%rax)` to dword operand-size.  It errors because of the ambiguity on `mov $1, (%rax)`, though!)

Answer (score 2):

First off, all of your numbers have an "h" at the end, which means they're hexadecimal numbers. Thus, the values you're storing aren't 10, 20, 30, etc, but are 16, 32, 48, etc. This means, for example, `mov cx, 10h` is actually setting cx to 16, not 10. Decimal constants don't need any suffix.

Second, when adding the numbers, the result will be greater than 255, which means it can't fit in a single byte. You'll need to use `ax` instead of `al` to keep track of the sum. Note this also means you'll need to modify the addition loop to convert each byte to a word.

Here's what the updated loop looks like:

```
mov ax, 0
mov cx, 10
mov dh, 0

lab: mov dl, [bx]
add ax, dx
dec bx
loop lab

mov bl, 10
div bl
```

Here I used `dx` to convert byte to word by setting `dh` to 0, then added `dx` to `ax`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!